# woocommerce 2.1 not recognising coupons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I've updated my Woocommerce to 2.1 and my old coupons do not work on checkout, I've found the only way it works is by view each coupon code via backend and click update it works fine.

Problem is I have 20k codes and going thought all the codes one by one will take ages.

How do I update all of them at once?

Please help me thanks

Comment: So, what is your question? How to update all of them at once?

Comment: Yer how to update them all at once

Answer (score 0):

We just updated to 2.1.6 from 2.0.  We had a similar problem where a lot of our old coupons weren't working.  For us though, the coupons which didn't work were the ones that had uppercase characters.  Did you notice the same? If so, it seems to be an issue with the class-wc-coupon.php file. Our fix is below.

In the class constructor (around line 140) there is a conditional that looks like this

```
if ( empty( $coupon ) || $this->code !== $coupon->post_title )
```

Change it to

```
if ( empty( $coupon ) || $this->code !== $this->post_title )
```

The reason for this is that the apply_filters (woocommerce_coupon_code) isn't applied on the $coupon->post_title variable and so any code with uppercase characters is being checked against the $this->code which had the filters already applied to it to ensure it's lowercase.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Editing core plugin files is not recommended due to the fact they get over written the next time the plugin is updated by the author.